# Create Retention Label Policy using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

I am trying to Create Retention Label Policy where i can group the Retention Label and publish to SharePoint Site using Powershell.
Want to achieve below functionality using powershell

"The primary purpose of a retention label policy is to group a set of retention labels and specify the locations where you want those labels to appear. "

[Label Policy Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR7aw.png)

Comment: Do you have any code you've already tried? Details on how it failed and/or produced a different result from what you were expecting would be helpful here. Did you notice that there is a PowerShell sample-script for this task (or perhaps partially) [further along in the documentation?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/bulk-create-publish-labels-using-powershell?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: I didn't get any powershell cmdlet to achieve the same. I have seen the sample-script but didn't find code to create Label Policy

Comment: I clearly must be missing something as the sample script claims to solve the following major steps `Create retention labels`, `Create retention policies` & `Publish retention labels for the policies`. Did you read up on the documentation for the cmdlet [New-RetentionCompliancePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-retentioncompliancepolicy)?

Comment: New-RetentionCompliancePolicy will create Retention Policy but i am talking about Label Policy
Adding ScreenShot

Comment: I have to say that the title of the second step [Step 2: Create a .csv file for the retention label policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/bulk-create-publish-labels-using-powershell?view=o365-worldwide#step-2-create-a-csv-file-for-the-retention-label-policies) seems wildly misleading if it doesn't do what you are asking for. Especially so considering sub-step 3, `Replace the examples with entries for your own retention label policies and their settings. For more information about the parameter values for this cmdlet, see New-RetentionCompliancePolicy.`

Answer (score 0):

Just worked through this and the behaviour is:

1. New-ComplianceTag (Contains the Actions)
2. New-RetentionCompliancePolicy (Contains the Locations)
3. New-RetentionComplianceRule (Binds the Actions to the Locations)

Although it looks like just a Retention Policy at Step 2 when you join it to a Label in Step 3 it becomes a Label Policy.

Repeat Step 3 using different Labels & the same policy (Locations) to publish multiple labels to the same areas.

This is what it will look like in the Label Policies interface after executing Step 3 with 2 different labels but the Same Policy:
[Security and Compliance Centre Label Policy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxBfB.png)